# Why isn't local-name() returning anything?

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to run the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(., 'ATTITUDE_')]/text()">
 <xsl:variable name="ElementName" select="local-name()"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vVal" select= "$vAttitudes[. = substring-after(current(), '_')]/@val"/>
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($ElementName, 'Refuse')">
      <xsl:value-of select="civf:book-capitalise($vAttitudes[@val = $vVal+1])"/>
    </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="civf:book-capitalise($vAttitudes[@val = $vVal])"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

So the premise is, find the name of the element, if it has the text "Refuse" in the name of it then "doTheThing"+1 otherwise just "doTheThing". However this test always fails so +1 never gets called even if the element has "Refuse" in the name. If I just output local-name then I get empty too. Why does local-name() not appear to work here?

I did previously try to start the template with:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(., 'Refuse')]/name()">
```

But Saxon complained that I was running too many functions in the match sequence.

I apologise in advance for not knowing too much about XSLT.

Comment: Please re-indent the code so that `<xsl:variable/>` doesn't increase indent level. It is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that `local-name()` does not work because you are matching text nodes (`/text()` in the `match` attribute), and text nodes do not have local names.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do but I don't think you actually want to match `/text()` but instead the whole element, and obtain its `text()` afterwards.

Alternatively, you could try using `local-name(..)` to get the name of parent node but I'm not sure about that.